# Put request edits not updating in database but no error either

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

My database has 'events' that I can create & delete, but have suddenly lost the ability to edit them. Every other request type works and even when I submit the edit, the routes don't show errors and I'm redirected to the proper page. I've included my two edit requests below (get and put) from my routes-> events.js, as well as my delete request since that one is working just fine.

```
/* serves the edit form */
router.get('/:id/edit', isLoggedIn, catchAsync(async(req, res,) => {
    const event = await Event.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!event) {
        req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that Event');
        return res.redirect('/events');
    }
    res.render('events/edit', { event });
}));

/* route that isn't pushing edits to the db */
router.put('/:id', isLoggedIn, catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const event = await Event.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.event });
    res.redirect(`/events/${event.id}`);
}))

/* delete a post - works just fine */
router.delete('/:id', isLoggedIn, catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const{ id } = req.params;
    await Event.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    res.redirect('/events');
}))
```

Here's the form:

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate')%>
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="text-center">Edit Event</h1>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <form action="/events/<%=event.id%>?_method=PUT" method="POST" novalidate class="validated-form"
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="title">Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="event[event_name]"
                    value="<%=event.event_name %>" required>
                <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Looks good!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="location">Location</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="location" name="event[location]"
                    value="<%=event.location %>" required>
                <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Looks good!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Update event</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="/events/<%= event.id%>">Back To event</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Alright - as soon as I posted the question I figured it out (love how that works).

My form fields didn't match the DB schema. Updated the form control fields to below:

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate')%>
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="text-center">Edit Event</h1>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <form action="/events/<%=event.id%>?_method=PUT" method="POST" novalidate class="validated-form"
            <div> class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[event_name]">Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="event[event_name]" name="event[event_name]"
                    value="<%=event.event_name %>" required>
                <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Looks good!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[location]">Location</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="event[location]" name="event[location]"
                    value="<%=event.location %>" required>
                <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Looks good!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Update event</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="/events/<%= event.id%>">Back To event</a>
    </div>
</div>
```